# Unable to do RSH connection

Tags: networking, remote-control, xinetd, rsh

I have two servers with RHEL 6.6 installed. I'm trying to do an RSH connection between these two. Following are the errors which I'm getting:

```
connect to address 172.21.70.95 port 544: Connection refused
trying normal rsh (/usr/bin/rsh)
poll: protocol failure in circuit setup
```

One server was able to do the RSH connection to a third server when it was on another network. But on this network, it is not able to do the same.

Same configurations are done here on this network and on both the servers but still, I'm facing this issue.

Comment: It would be easier and more secure to set up and use SSH rather than RSH. Easier, because RSH has been mostly phased out and everyone and their grandmother uses SSH instead (there is therefore (arguably) more SSH knowledge out there than RSH knowledge). More secure, because SSH.

Comment: That connection refused presumably means either you don't have the rsh server enabled on .95, or alternatively you have firewall rules blocking the connection.

Comment: RSH is one of the requirements for the certification which I'm running on my hardware. - @Kusalananda

Comment: Need more information to properly troubleshoot. What are the IPs of the two RHEL 6.6 servers? Is there a firewall **between** these servers and the destination 172.21.70.95? What is the contents of `/etc/hosts.equiv` on 172.21.70.95, as well as `~root/.rhosts` and any other users' `$HOME/.rhosts` file. Port 513 is the normal port used for `rsh` and `rlogin`, port 544 is for an rsh connection utilizing Kerberos. May need to add Kerberos configuration to the two RHEL servers.

Comment: Servers IPs are 172.21.70.95 and 172.21.70.110. There is no firewall between these servers. Contents of `.rhosts` files are `+ +` and that of `/etc/hosts.equiv` is the hostname of 172.21.70.110 server. And I don't have any idea why it is running on port 544.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsh shows "poll: protocol failure in circuit setup", why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68310/rsh-shows-poll-protocol-failure-in-circuit-setup-why)