# After restarting xinetd service, rsh shows "poll: protocol failure in circuit setup"

Tags: xinetd, rsh

I have searched a lot in various forums and most indicate that the solution is to open ports in the firewall or restart the `xinetd` service. Although that may be the solution in some cases, I think the problem is another and is still pending solution.

I have Red Hat 6, `iptables` service is off, and I have not modified the executables `rshd`/`rsh`.

Initially, when I start the system, rsh works fine:

```
# rsh localhost pwd
/root
```

If I simply restart the service "xinetd", I get the known message "poll: protocol failure in circuit setup":

```
# service xinetd restart
Stopping xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
# rsh localhost pwd
poll: protocol failure in circuit setup
```

I have only been able to fix the problem in two ways: rebooting the system or going through level 2.

```
# init 2; sleep 1; init 3
# rsh localhost pwd
/root
```

I'd like to reach the root cause. It is not a firewall problem.

**This is the `strace` output when it fails:**
(see highlighted passage)

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1023), in_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETOWN, 23277)               = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(514), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1022), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 1)                            = 0
write(3, "1022\0", 5)                   = 5
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
write(2, "poll: protocol failure in circui"..., 40) = 40
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], [URG], 8) = 0
exit_group(1)
```

**This is the `strace` output when it works fine:**
(see highlighted passage)

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1023), in_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETOWN, 24718)               = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(514), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1022), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 1)                            = 0
write(3, "1022\0", 5)                   = 5
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
accept(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1020), in_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 5
close(4)                                = 0
writev(3, [{"root\0", 5}, {"root\0", 5}, {"pwd\0", 4}], 3) = 14
read(3, "\0", 1)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], [URG], 8) = 0
setuid(0)                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT QUIT TERM], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x2abd2db30080, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_IGN, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x2abd2db30080, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_IGN, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [TERM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x2abd2db30080, [TERM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, {SIG_IGN, [TERM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x2abd2e3c1920}, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2abd2eb893b0) = 24721
ioctl(5, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
ioctl(3, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], [INT QUIT TERM], 8) = 0
select(6, [3 5], NULL, NULL, NULL)      = 1 (in [3])
read(3, "/root\n", 8192)                = 6
write(1, "/root\n", 6)                  = 6
select(6, [3 5], NULL, NULL, NULL)      = 1 (in [3])
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [5])
read(5, "", 8192)                       = 0
kill(24721, SIGKILL)                    = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Octavio

Comment: If you don’t mind me asking, why are you using a dead protocol on a dead platform in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsh shows "poll: protocol failure in circuit setup", why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68310/rsh-shows-poll-protocol-failure-in-circuit-setup-why)

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Can you show us the xinetd config file for rsh?

Comment: This is the config file /etc/xinetd.d/rsh
service shell
{
        socket_type        = stream
        wait                     = no
        user                    = root
        log_on_success  += USERID
        log_on_failure     += USERID
        server                  = /usr/sbin/in.rshd
        disable                = no
}

Comment: We keep a system on the client under closed configuration control. The system used must be this.

Comment: The indicated thread [ rsh shows "poll: protocol failure in circuit setup, why?" ] does not answer my question. Although the symptom is the same, in my case I have not modified the source code of rsh/rshd nor is it a firewall problem because it occurs on the local machine and iptables is disabled.

Comment: The /var/log/messages shows this error:  rshd[5251]: Could not allocate space for cmdbuf
I think this can be a rshd bug. So if it has no solution without modifying the souce code, I would at least recover the service rshd in a smooth way. At the moment, it can be restablished in two ways:
1. reboot (too drastic)
2. init 2; sleep 1; init 3 (or init 5)

I have tried this to recover it (unsuccessfully):

cd /etc/init.d
./xinetd stop; ./rpcbind stop; ./portreserve stop; ./network stop; sleep 2; ./network start; ./portreserve start; ./rpcbind start; ./xinetd start

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you wait a few minutes after the `poll: protocol failure in circuit setup` failure - enough that all the connections in TIME_WAIT in `netstat -atp` go away - and try rsh again, does it still fail?